# Cygwin failing to open .git/config

Tags: windows, git, cygwin

I believe that I am missing something obvious.

I am using Windows 8.1 in VMWare Fusion on a Mac OS X host. I have installed Git as a Windows component, and I also installed Git as a Cygwin component.

I was able to use all my usual Git commands on Cygwin within a versioned directory. However, when I tried to push, I was notified that I have not yet associated my e-mail or name (`git config --global user.name <name>; git config --global user.email <email address>`).

When I ran those commands, I got a permission denied. Afterward, I was unable to issue ANY git command (`status; show; pull; fetch; etc...`).

I received the following error in Cygwin:

`fatal: permission denied opening .git/config`

**UPDATE:** I seemed to have resolved this by deleting my Cygwin `C:\cygwin64\home\<user>\.gitconfig` file. Any idea what may have been going on?

I believe that there is an issue when a `.gitconfig` is in the Cygwin home directory and there's a config file in the actual `C:\Users\<user>\.git\` folder.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try running Cygwin with administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have resolved this by deleting my Cygwin C:\cygwin64\home\.gitconfig file.